# Remove image when clicked

Tags: javascript

Basically, I'm trying to create a game where the goal is to click on images so they disappear.

I've made a function that spawns one image on a random location on the screen. Then I've also made an interval so it spawns 15 images in random locations. Now I want the images to disappear when clicked on.

My thoughts on doing this were to make a "click" function, so if the images are clicked the "img.style.height = '0px';

However, I'm not getting this or anything to work.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `onclick="this.remove();"`?

Comment: So i have this function here, and ive also created a interval that will generate 15 images appear on the screen. Now i need them to disappear when clicked on.

https://jsfiddle.net/dtzugdq5/1/

Comment: So you can implement it [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/dtzugdq5/2/), but check Saeed.Ataee's answer, because it's looks OK to me. If it was helpful than you can accept it

Comment: hmm, I tried it but it only freezes the screen/ nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1):

After you insert all images in document, define a `click` listener for all images and hide images on click. A simple example here

```js
function hide(el) {
  el.style.display = 'none';
}

var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for(let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i ++) {
imgs[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  hide(e.target);
});
}
```

```html
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTgYxw854mGOAp8f16evj_WYw_Ph385nUVygQdxHvuD9b3ueJxT0A" id="1" alt="Mountain View 1">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT8_MiTkMX9nLJ9udtnwOQekIrQwUQ9KMZiU4fLfI7YhXCyIGZn" id="2" alt="Mountain View 2">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRgR4KM-zrVRmfdGPf5bll9vq4uLw7FSLpTmHUf9-RkYZ92Ey8Q" id="3" alt="Mountain View 3">
```

---

Your code should change like this

```js
function SpawnW() {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;");
  img.setAttribute("src", "women3.png");
  document.body.appendChild(img);
  img.setAttribute("onclick", "this.style.display = 'none'");
  // pictureNumber++;
}

SpawnW();
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank for all the support, however, ive created a "var img = document.createElement('img'); and dont have any img in html, does it still work the same then?

Comment: As user2314737 you can use `img.setAttribute("onclick", "this.style.display = 'none'" );` in your code, after definition of image tag. Or you can call this for loop, after all image insertion. @Kberg

Comment: Thanks! this helped me a lot.

Comment: Your welcome, Good luck. You can accept the answer if it is true. @Kberg

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<img onclick="this.style.visibility = 'hidden'" src="..." />
```

if you want to leave the space occupied by the image, otherwise:

```
<img onclick="this.style.display = 'none'" src="..." />
```

If you need to remove the image from an array of objects, you need to define a function as well.

In your code:

```
img.setAttribute("onclick", "this.style.visibility = 'hidden'" );
```

or

```
img.setAttribute("onclick", "this.style.display = 'none'" );
```

Comment: Thanks all, the problem was that I did not define it in the function. Thanks!